# Why do bash variables disappear when I use xargs?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, xargs

I have a simple bash script and want to count how often a command gets called. Here is a minimal example, the counter is called c and should be 4 at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0;
for a in X Y; do
  for b in 1 2; do
    c="$(( ${c} + 1 ))"
    echo "${a}${b}"
  done #| xargs -L 1 -P 20 echo
  echo "count $c"
done
echo "--"
echo "final $c"
```

Works great without xargs (final=4), but when I uncomment the pipe to xargs it counts nothing (final=0). Why?

```
Expected output: |  This happens with xargs:
X1               |  X1
X2               |  X2
count 2          |  count 0
Y1               |  Y1
Y2               |  Y2
count 4          |  count 0
--               |  --
final 4          |  final 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe means that your for loop is happening in a subshell, which doesn't pass $c back to the rest of your program.  You'll need to rewrite without the pipe.  [This StackOverflow question is pretty similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237048/bashs-cat-while-let-and-pipe-lead-to-strange-scoping-behavior).  The `<( )` syntax might be your friend here.

Comment: In this case, I think `>( )` is the form wanted. Something like `... done > >(xargs ... )`

Comment: `xargs.. < <(for..)` did not work, fixed it by writing all results to a file first and then calling xargs. But my question here was why, so thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gordon, sorry, didn't see your answer before posting, but it doesn't seem to work here, I only get Y1 X2 Y2 and then it hangs, weird.